# Continuity of a complex variable function.

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers, continuity

> Let $$ f(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
>              \frac{z^3-1}{z^2+z+1} &   if   & |z| \neq 1 \\
>              \\ \frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2} & if & |z|=1 \\
>              \end{array}
>    \right.
> $$
> is $f$ continous in $z_0=\frac{1+ \sqrt{3}i}{2}$

I think to $f$ is not continous at $z_0$, i try using the sequence criterion for continuity searching a sequence $\{z_n\}$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}z_n=z_0$ but $\lim_{n \to \infty}f(z_n)\neq f(z_0)$.
but i cant find that sequence, ill be very grateful for any hint or help to solve my problem.

Comment: Perhaps that you meant $f(z)$ rather than $f(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, if $|z|\ne1$,$$f(z)=\frac{z^3-1}{z^2+z+1}=\frac{(z-1)(z^2+z+1)}{z^2+z+1}=z-1$$and that$$\lim_{z\to z_0}z-1=\frac{-1+\sqrt3i}2.$$So, $f$ *is* continuous at $z_0$.

Actually, this argument only works for $z_0$. In fact, $f$ is discontinuous at every other point of the unit circle.

Comment: You may want to add that it is the only point on $|z| = 1$ where $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @Ilya Nice suggestion! Done.